# Publicar app em Xamarin para Android 5 na Google Play

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play

A Google Play não está permitindo eu publicar um aplicativo que rode em Android menor que 8.0. Estou usando as seguintes configurações:

- Compile using Android version: 8.1
- Minimum Android version: 5.0
- Target Android version: Use Compile using SDK version

É alguma configuração errada?

Answer (score 2):

RESOLVIDO

O problema estava em **Target Android version** que não pode ficar "Use Compile using SDK version", deve ficar definido a versão explicita do Android, no caso, 26 ou superior.

Answer (score 1):

É isso mesmo, a versão mínima atualmente é a 8, você não vai conseguir enviar apps com versões anteriores.

**Fonte:**

Todo APK tem um targetSdkVersion no arquivo de manifesto, também conhecido como o nível desejado da API. Essa versão informa como seu app é executado em diferentes versões do Android.

Configurar o app para segmentar níveis de API recentes garante que os usuários terão melhorias na segurança e no desempenho. Ao mesmo tempo, o app poderá ser executado em versões mais antigas do Android (até a minSdkVersion).

O APK enviado por você precisa atender aos requisitos de nível de API do Google Play. Veja os níveis que os apps precisam segmentar atualmente e no futuro.

Requisito de nível de API   Android 8.0 (nível 26 de API)

```
1º de agosto de 2018: necessário para novos apps
1º de novembro de 2018: necessário para atualizações de apps
```

Android 9 (nível 28 de API)

```
1º de agosto de 2019: necessário para novos apps
1º de novembro de 2019: necessário para atualizações de apps
```

Após esses requisitos entrarem em vigor, o Play Console impedirá o envio de novos APKs por meio de níveis desejados de API mais antigos.

Dica: para orientações técnicas sobre como alterar o nível desejado da API do seu app para cumprir esses requisitos, consulte o guia de migração.

fonte: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=pt-BR#targetsdk

Comment: Eu vi isso, mas ai fala **"Ao mesmo tempo, o app poderá ser executado em versões mais antigas do Android"**, ou seja, dá a entender que é possível usar em versão 7, 6,... .

A unica solução que eu encontrei foi aumentar a versão mínima para 8, mas as pessoas que irão utilizar possuem celulares antigos.

Comment: Então Afonso está meio confuso mesmo, mas eu entendi que você não vai conseguir enviar o app, maaas tente o seguinte : minSdkVersion 21 e targetSdkVersion 26. se não funcionar realmente está bloqueado o envio